# how to add a value from text box to a table in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `text_fields` and a `table` with three column. By clicking the button, i want that two `text_field` value added to the tables in the first two columns. So, the user can change the `text_field` values again and again and the values added to the next row by clicking the add `button`.

The two `text_fields` are as follows:

```
<input class="cross-reference-question-value" type="text" style="border: 1px solid gray;  ">
<input class="cross-reference-answer-value" type="text" style="border: 1px solid gray;  ">
```

Here is the `table`

```
<table class="gridView" id="selected_units">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gridViewHeader">
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody> 
    <tr class="<%= cycle('gridViewclickableRowDialog', 'gridViewAltclickableRowDialog') %>">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `button_link` is

```
<a href="#" , class="button" >hello</a>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I am a very newbie to javascript. I am still struggling to get that.

Comment: Please remove the downvote. I am very new to javascript and learning. Please dont discourage me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with this:

```
​$('.button').click(function() {
    var question = $('.cross-reference-question-value').val();
    var answer = $('.cross-reference-answer-value').val();
    var newrow = '<tr><td>' + question + '</td><td>' + answer + '</td></tr>';
    $('#selected_units tr:last').after(newrow);
});​​​​​
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JM9qX/). Add checks for empty inputs, duplicate rows, etc.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to add the delete button to every row. I want to delete the row by clicking that button.